# Question about doing a double slit on two entangled particles

Tags: quantum-entanglement, double-slit-experiment

Let me start by saying I am not a physics major, math and computer science but I have been reading everything I can about the double slit and entanglement and cannot seem to find the exact  answer to my question. So here goes

So I have an entangle generator     creating particles p1 and p2 such that

screen1---Double Slit1-------p1--------generator------p2----double slit2---screen2

Part 1 , From a previous reading, I understand without a measurement detector at either double slit site the particles will create an interference pattern at both locations, regardless of any time difference on when they hit.  I think I also read that since the frequency is random? that the pattern will be a mess and not clean like you would see with a uniform frequency, but an interference pattern non the less  of a bunch of random frequencies, so is this statement true?

Part 2 now assuming part 1 is true, if I put a detector (to see which slit the particle is going through) on double slit 2 , that will collapse the wave function of particle 2 and I will see a pattern with the just the two slits mirrored  on the detector screen 2 as in a  traditional double slit experiment.   So what happens on screen 1 now , assume screen 1 is slightly farther away from the generator than screen 2, such that particle two hits the screen 1 after the detection is attempted on particle 2?

thanks if advance

Answer (score -1):

When two particles are entangled, then they are entangled in terms of specific degrees of freedom. Assuming the particles are photons for argument sake, then they carry spin (polarization), temporal (wavelength) and spatial (modal) degrees of freedom. Two photons can be entangled in any or a combination of these degrees of freedom. Say for instance they are only entangled in terms of polarization. Then detection schemes based on frequency (wavelength) will not show any correlations due to entanglement.

So, in your scheme, if you make a specific measurement on one side then it will only affect the other side if the measurement restricts the degree of freedom that is entangled. Moreover, to see the effect of entanglement, you would need to make a correlation measurement in which you simultaneously measure the particles on both sides, using a coincidence counter for example. Otherwise you won't be able to see the effect of the entanglement.

Does this help?

Comment: Thank you for your answers, but No sorry I don't quite understand.  But  let me try to explain where I am confused... so in my scenario , where I am going is I am trying to discern if there is any way to collapse the wave function on p1  in a deterministic  way by measuring anything on P2 , such that I can force p1 to act as a particle going through the slits.    Are you saying with an entangled particle I cannot simple "detect" it but I must detect it's spin angle, and /or frequency component?    And as for simultaneously  is that even possible?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I did not down vote , I don't even know how to vote, Thanks for the answer, my lack of understanding is mine to solve

Comment: when I have more time, I'll elaborate